# Probability for Lottery tickets

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, lotteries

I have no idea on how to solve this. Can someone help?
Q: In the first lottery the ratio of winning tickets to losing tickets is 1 to 2, and in the second lottery is 3 to 1. After mixing the tickets from two lotteries the probability of the winning is the same as losing.
Calculate how many tickets is in the first and in the second lottery, if there are 300 in both.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the number of tickets in first lottery and $b$ be the number in the second.  Then $a+b=300$.  Since the number of losers equals the number of winners, there must be $150$ losers in the mixed lottery.

In terms of $a$ and $b$, write an expression for the total number of losers.  Set it equal to $150$.  Now you have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: You're perfect. Thank you so much. I followed your steps and got a=180  and b=120